# Can I use Flask Restful alongside an existing Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have been tasked with working on an existing Flask project (Flask with Templates/Jinja2 style monolith application). I have to add new features to this app and I'm also intending to re-design the app so it becomes a more micro-services based architecure (i.e. initially Flask-restful based backend with React based front-end). Can I just use Flask-restful by just wrapping the existing app and start creating the new endpoints using `Resource`?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

Are there any specific caveats/gotcha's I need to worry about?

Answer (score 3):

Let's try it and see what happens. We start with a basic Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "This is index\n"


@app.route("/endpoint1")
def endpoint1():
    return "This is endpoint1\n"
```

This works and we can request the `/` and `/endpoint1` endpoints and get the expected response:

```
$ curl localhost:5000
This is index
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint1
This is endpoint1
```

Let's see if we can mash a `flask_restful` managed endpoint in there without disrupting the existing functionality:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Widgets(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return make_response('Yes we have no widgets today\n')


api.add_resource(Widgets, '/widgets')


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "This is index\n"


@app.route("/endpoint1")
def endpoint1():
    return "This is endpoint1\n"
```

Are our original routes still active?

```
$ curl localhost:5000
This is index
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint1
This is endpoint1
```

How about the new one?

```
$ curl localhost:5000/widgets
Yes we have no widgets today
```

It looks like the answer is "yes"!